Why did Leto II change his wedding location to Tuono Village, despite the obvious danger?
I just finished re-reading God Emperor of Dune and the final bit where Leto II is setting up his marriage ceremony seems awfully silly and careless when considered at the surface level:

Tuono Village was a location poorly suited for the marriage ceremony in multiple ways
He changed the location at the last second, giving Moneo inadequate time to set everything up, most of all the security
These changes upset and frustrated Moneo terribly, far more than was usual for the normally subservient majordomo, and Leto deliberately ignored his objections
He chose Tuono Village knowing full well Duncan and Siona were there and both of them wanted to assassinate him
The procession went across a bridge, which was an obvious vulnerable point, especially given that Leto's major weakness is water

There are some other points I could make too, but overall it doesn't take a Kwisatz Haderach to figure out what was likely to happen.
Leto II certainly wasn't stupid nor was he suicidal, so he must have had his reasons for doing this. The best attempt I can make at working it out is that he was always following his prescient vision along the Golden Path, and that vision drove him to make these changes, in spite of the danger, since setting up his probable death this way allowed the Golden Path to continue, perhaps irreversibly so. He also knew that he had achieved a human who was invisible to prescient vision with Siona, and perhaps concluded that his reign could finally come to an end.
That all said, I don't recall there being anything in the book that fully explains it. Does my explanation make sense? Or is there something else going on in Leto's head that I missed?

Nope, that's what I recall too. He saw the Golden Path that required his death and so arranged things so it would happen. But it's been a while.

He stated himself that he didn't know the when or the players in that act, but he "knew the way of it". Yes, he knew it was necessary and the fulfilment of his life's purpose. The decision sprang from that and his relationship to Duncan, Siona and Nayla and the opportunity it presented. The writing's internal narrative was great for exposing inner states and thoughts, but unless one of the Bryan Herbert sequels reveals more of the Journals then that may be all we get on the topic.

Don't forget Leto's relationship with, and focus on Hwi and the jealousy of her and Duncan's liaison - an opportunity to laude his victory (marriage) over the man buoyed his spirits and distracted him from the danger (my supposition).

Leto appears to do a wide range of things with the sole intention of annoying Moneo, who he sees as overprotective.

@JiminyCricket. While it's true that Leto does a lot of things to amuse himself given the drudgery of being alive for 3500 years with prescient vision spoiling a lot of surprises, I don't think he would make a major decision based on a somewhat petty motivation. It always has to be in service of the Golden Path, and I think he must have been aware of the danger at least in some capacity.

The danger was him dying away from water - the beast, the "underground" part of him frequently surfaced in response to strong emotion. I wouldn't call it petty so much as driven. @BriBri

He deliberately chose Tuono village because Siona and Duncan were there and wanted to kill him. Leto II knows he cannot see Siona within the Golden Path; he has bred the line to give this gift to the future so knows his prescience may not give warning of possible danger.
So why change the location? he is testing them.
All throughout the book he is continually testing people and when they fail it is death (such as the initial introduction of Siona with the death of many of her companions, the many deaths of the Duncan over the millenia). This is the Golden Path; forced evolution through overcoming adversity. Leto II is the apex predator and the ultimate test would be to overcome him. He is giving Siona a chance to prove her future path. If she fails, she would die and Leto II would go back to trying to breed a stronger adversary.
*** Update ***
Original question mentioned Moneo was more upset than normal and this hasn't really been addressed.
Moneo is aware Leto II wants to further test Siona and he is rightfully scared that there is a chance she will be killed - he also remembers his past testing, how difficult it was and how it changed him. Leto II may not want to actually kill her as she carries the precious genes for hiding from his path but as Moneo has seen many times in the past, Leto II also has the worm within which is an instinctual killer when he gets angry. As a result Moneo contrived to have Siona and Duncan taken to Tuono village where they wouldn't be able to interfere with the wedding. Therefore when Leto II alters his plans once he learns what Moneo has done, it once again puts Siona within reach of the worm and counters Moneo's careful planning. This is why it upsets him so much.
In terms of his 'prescient vision', Leto II really wasn't fully aware of his future path; this was the lesson of Muad'dib and the Preacher where knowing the fullness of the future locked in that future path for the Preacher and Leto II although seeing where the Golden Path could lead would not allow only the one known path to exist. He needed limitless futures to work with and as a result would not have probed his own future without good reason.

I like this answer, as it explicitly fits within Leto's patterns and his self-described purpose (granted his descriptions can be somewhat vague, poetic and enigmatic and therefore open to interpretation). And it explains how and why he would be aware of the danger (and no need for prescience for that) but demand that he be put into it anyway.

@BriBri - But there are bits and pieces of prescience and Leto knows. His ultimate goal is the humanity's invisibility to prescience, and nothing is to prevent that. Also, in prior books, Leto II clearly states that only through him sandworms will return to Dune, so he literally knows, in general, how he dies. But the best part is: since he's prescient, he yearned for a surprise, any surprise. Bonus: if Siona succeeds, then this is his time to go, nothing more left for him to do.

He is fully aware of it, he foresaw it and knew it was part of the golden path. He needed the scattering to occur he needed a liberation of mankind to happen only could happen when he is murdered. Keep in mind the fish seers must be angered for their part so a quick way to achieve both is murder.

Just like the plot involving the Guild, the presence of Siona blinds Leto. He clearly can't see his own death, noting that he would never risk harm to Hwi if he could help it.

Leto also makes it clear that he never uses his prescient vision to look into his own death, so in this case he didn't know the outcome. But I still maintain the likely outcome is fairly obvious without prescience, and Leto at least knew there was serious danger. So @Valorum brings up a good point: why did he knowingly put Hwi in danger?

@BriBri - Hwi would approve of his decision. She's literally designed to do so.

@Valorum Indeed she would! But Leto would strongly disapprove of putting her in danger, and it's his whims that matter. So I feel like her being there is a case against Leto recognizing the danger. On the other hand, though, he also knew that Duncan desperately wanted to keep her alive, so maybe he was counting on her surviving any assassination attempt.

@Valorum - I don't think you're correct on the "He clearly can't see his own death" part. I believe he had some bits and flashes from it: <<“Lord, let us hold your wedding in some other place.”
“No!”
“Lord, I know that your vision has revealed …”
“The Golden Path endures, Moneo. You know that as well as I.”>>  God Emperor of Dune, p.430

@AcePL - He can see actions that do and don't result in the Golden Path continuing, specifically anything that results in his death away from water

Prescient beings get used to knowing what lies ahead and avoiding the pitfalls, when they can't see any pitfalls they feel safe to carry on with whatever they have planned even where a non-prescient making an objective assessment sees serious  dangers. Leto II knew he had to die at some stage, in order to ensure the continuity of his Golden Path, the exact details involved another prescient being (or at least someone invisible to prescient vision) so he couldn't see the how or when of the thing. Foreseeing no danger in his wedding, wherever he decided to hold it, he went ahead with having it wherever his whim took him.
